# Finding path of application using VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

In a VB application I am building, I need to launch Outlook. Obviously, on every computer the path to Outlook will not be the same. Thus, I need to know how to find the path of Outlook on the user's computer before I Shell("path"). How would I do this?

Comment: Oops, please forgive my wrong “close” vote. I was too trigger happy.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603287/references-in-microsoft-visual-studio-not-working if you are wanting to access outlook from withing your app.

Answer (score 4):

Usually Outlook is installed into the environment path, so you could just use:

```
 Process.Start("Outlook.exe")
```

Answer (score 3):

First, the user might have multiple versions of Outlook installed.

You could try this registry path:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\OUTLOOK.EXE\Path
```

...Works for me!

If you're going to send an email, etc, by the way, you could run the commandline, `mailto:address@here.com` - look at the `mailto:` protocol.  It will launch any email client.

Comment: Perfect solution for me. Awesome and thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to send mail via outlook (or any default email client), you can always just shell `mailto:name@host.com`, which will create a new mail message with the email in the subject line.  You can also append other variables using an HTML email shell.

*Otherwise...*

You can check if Microsoft Office is installed, and grab the path via the registry.  You can then navigate to the Outlook directory  e.g.

```
Sub CheckOfficeXPInstalled()
   InstallRoot = System.PrivateProfileString("", _
 "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\10.0\Common\InstallRoot", _
 "Path")
   If InstallRoot <> "" Then
     MsgBox "An Office XP Family Product is installed at " & InstallRoot
   End If
End Sub
```

See [How to programatically determine if Microsoft Office is installed](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office-xp-resource-kit/how-to-determine-programmatically-if-office-xp-is-installed-HA001136461.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You don't lauch Outlook by finding its exe.

You launch it by creating it.

```
Dim o As Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
o.Visible = True
```

(Requires `Option Strict Off`)

Comment: That looks a bit leaky.  Is there no cleanup to be done afterwards?

Comment: @Kieren Provided you launch it for the user, not really. Otherwise, `o.Close` and `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(o)`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the version of Office you're using but, for Office 2010 on 64-bit Windows the Microsoft Office install root folder is held in the `Path` value under the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\InstallRoot`. For 32-bit Windows remove the `Wow6432Node`. `OUTLOOK.EXE` lives in the folder specified by this registry value.

Answer (score 0):

I think that one of the [.net environment variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77zkk0b6.aspx) will point to the default program files directory.  But if a user installs anywhere this you may simply have to use the [FileSystemObject object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50(v=vs.85).aspx) and run round the file system looking for outlook.exe.

Comment: @davide GetSpecialFolder looks good - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a72y2t1c(v=vs.85).aspx - rubbish name, mind!